# Unhandled exception, orgin unknown

Tags: c++, runtime-error, unhandled-exception

This is a homework assignment. I'm experiencing a weird error and I have no idea what is causing it. This is not the entire assignment, but it is what I have so far. As it's homework, I don't want someone to tell me exactly how to code it, rather I would like to know what is causing my crash and how I might be able to begin looking for how to solve it. My program seems to be crashing once it hits the return statement in the main method. All output appears to be exactly what I was trying to obtain, and my file is being read just fine. Once I hit enter after all my information has been printed, I'm presented with a message box that says "Unhandled exception at 0x5286ad84 (msvcp100d.dll) in Exams.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000063."
Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#define MAX_STUDENTS 100
#define MAX_QUESTIONS 50
using namespace std;

int fGetAnswers(FILE *p_inputf, int p_studentIds[], string p_studentAnswers[]);
int fGetAnswers(int p_studentIds[], string p_studentAnswers[]);
void printData(int numOfStudents, int numOfQuestions, string *p_correctAnswers, int studentIds[], string studentAnswers[]);

int main(void)
{
    // Declarations
    FILE *inputf = fopen("examdat.txt", "r"); // Opens "examdat.txt" and creates a pointer to it.
    int studentIds[MAX_STUDENTS];
    int *p_ids = studentIds; // Pointer to the studentIds array to pass to functions for manipulation.
    string studentAnswers[MAX_QUESTIONS];
    string *p_answers = studentAnswers; // Pointer to the studentAnswers array to pass to functions for manipulation.
    int numOfQuestions;
    string correctAnswers;
    int numOfStudents;
    fscanf(inputf, "%d %s", &numOfQuestions, correctAnswers); // Fetches the first line from the exam.dat file which contains the number of questions and the correct answers.

    int readFrom = 0;
    while (readFrom != 1 && readFrom != 2) // Loops until proper input is received. Asks if the user wants to read student data from the text file or enter it manually.
    {
        printf("1. Read student data from file.\n");
        printf("2. Enter student data manually.\n\n");
        printf("Please make a selection> ");
        scanf("%d", &readFrom);
        if (readFrom != 1 && readFrom != 2)
            printf("\nInvalid entry!\n");
    }
    if (readFrom == 1) // Calls fGetAnswers to retrieve answers from the text file.
        numOfStudents = fGetAnswers(inputf, p_ids, p_answers);
    else // Calls fGetAnswers to retrieve answers from the user via the keyboard.
        numOfStudents = fGetAnswers(p_ids, p_answers);

    fclose(inputf);

    printData(numOfStudents, numOfQuestions, &correctAnswers, studentIds, studentAnswers);

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: It's a c++ intro class where we're allowed to use a blend of both c and c++. I am very inexperienced and thought that my implementation was mostly c, but either is allowed so long as it compiles and produces the correct output in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I think, `string correctAnswers` and `fscanf ... %s` do not type-match. `fscanf` may expect a `char*`.

Comment: (This won't solve your problem) Don't pass pointers for the sake of it. For example, in printData( .. ), you pass a pointer to string.
Instead, change printData's signature to accept a reference to a constant string)
void printData(..., const string& correctAnswers, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a C++ compiler, you can undo a few C habits (earlier the better!)

```
#include <iostream> // for std::cout and std::cin

using namespace std::cin; 
using namespace std::cout;
using namespace std::endl;
```

Instead of printf (and the issue that john pointed out regarding C style strings), use:

```
cout << numOfQuestions << "\t" << correctAnswers << endl;
```

You can read about cout [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/)

Comment: You know you can say `using std::cin;` and `using std::cout;`. Saying `using namespace std;` is asking for trouble for any code longer than a handful of lines.

Comment: Thanks, I already am familiar with basic usage of cin and cout and the standard namespace. I don't know much about file reading and writing though... is there an option similar to fscanf in iostream? I decided to use printf and scanf initially with this project because I thought they went with fscanf. I didn't realize my strings were c++ style strings and that actually explains a lot. Why though would all my output still turn out right until it crashed? For example, printf("%d\t%s\n", numOfQuestions, *p_correctAnswers); properly outputs 5[TAB]dbbac which is exactly what I read in from examdat?

Comment: Yup - edited. 
Yes, that's the beauty of C++. Your file is just another "stream".
Once opened, you can read from and write to the file stream using >> and << operators.
For file input, you can look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Comment: Regarding the failure, your error msg states its a write issue.
printf seems to work (strangely) - I'd think its because your pointer to the string is the same as what .c_str() would generate, meaning that the characters are stored at the very beginning of the string container.

Comment: I'm working on converting to full usage of C++ for this program, but I'm not exactly sure how to read multiple things in at once the way I would with scanf. e.g. How would I write scanf("%d %s", &p_studentIds[i], p_studentAnswers[i]); as a cin statement? cin << &p_studentIds[i], p_studentAnswers[i] doesn't seem to work. Would it be better to read it in as a line and tokenize it by whitespace?

Comment: Nevermind. I think I've figured everything out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For others who view this post in the future, you may want to change using namespace std::cin and the others to using std::cin etc.

Answer (score 4):

There may be lots of errors, using a debugger will help you track them down. But two I spotted are

```
printf("%d\t%s\n", numOfQuestions, *p_correctAnswers);
```

You cannot use C++ strings with printf, only C strings. This will work

```
printf("%d\t%s\n", numOfQuestions, p_correctAnswers->c_str());
```

The c_str method returns a C style string from a C++ style string.

And another similar error

```
int result = fscanf(p_inputf, "%d %s", &p_studentIds[i], p_studentAnswers[i]);
```

you cannot use C++ strings with fscanf. This one is hard to solve. Since you want to use C++ strings (which is a smart move) I think you should also learn some C++ I/O, look up *iostreams*.

Comment: +1 for the bug found, but I'm not sure if "learn to use a debugger" is a good advice. Letting bugs in with the idea of removing them later doesn't work so well in general and especially in languages with UB.

Comment: @6502 OK, I've moderated my language a little.